# RabbitListener to retry only for a particular exception

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-rabbit

How do I make my RabbitListener retry only when there is an exception while consuming the message and not for any other exception? In other words, I want the listener to retry only for a particular exception and not for other exceptions. Currently, it is retrying for all the exceptions. Can this be configured via config files?

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions like this, it's best to show your existing configuration.

It cannot be configured with properties.

You need to add a retry interceptor to the container factory with a retry policy that has exceptions classified for retry or not.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#retry

You can add a recoverer to the interceptor (such as the `RepublishMessageRecoverer` to send failed messages to another queue).